# How insert records into a table from another table with conditions

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working on a program which contains an `Insert into` statement, and I would like to add some conditions to it.

Let's say that the `TARGET_TABLE` has 2 primary key columns called `A, B` and 1 variable C (whose values are "NO" or "YES").

And same for the `SOURCE_TABLE`.

1. If the record in the `SOURCE_TABLE` does not exist in the `TARGET_TABLE` then insert it
2. If there is already a record present in the `TARGET_TABLE` with same values for the primary key columns, and with variable C = "NO", then update the record **only if** the new record has a variable C = "YES"
3. If there is already a record present in the `TARGET_TABLE` with same values for the primary key columns, and with variable C = "YES", then don't insert

Do you have some ideas? I was trying with the "where not exists" then I tried using "Case when" but I can't figure out how to mix the 3 cases in the same program...

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Not really... @JeffHolt because i don't know how mix the 3 cases on same program :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this `merge` covers all cases (Oracle solution):

```
merge into target_table t
using source_table s
on (t.a = s.a and t.b = s.b)
when matched then update set d = s.d, c = s.c where t.c = 'NO' and s.c = 'YES'
when not matched then insert values (s.a, s.b, s.c, s.d)
```

So for these sample data:

```
create table target_table(a, b, c, d) as (
   select 1, 2, 'NO',  100 from dual union all
   select 1, 3, 'NO',  100 from dual union all
   select 1, 4, 'NO',  100 from dual union all
   select 1, 5, 'YES', 100 from dual );

create table source_table(a, b, c, d) as (
   select 1, 1, 'NO',  200  from dual union all
   select 1, 3, 'YES', 200  from dual union all
   select 1, 4, 'NO',  200  from dual union all
   select 1, 5, 'YES', 200  from dual );
```

you get:

```
     A          B C            D
------ ---------- --- ----------
     1          1 NO         200
     1          2 NO         100
     1          3 YES        200
     1          4 NO         100
     1          5 YES        100
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a63c20780a6a8389353120f2f4e5f59e)</sup>**

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (pk, a, b)
SELECT pk, a, b
FROM SOURCE_TABLE s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT NULL FROM TARGET_TABLE t WHERE s.pk = t.pk
)

UPDATE t
SET b = s.b
FROM TARGET_TABLE t
    INNER JOIN SOURCE_TABLE s ON t.pk = s.pk
WHERE t.a = 'Yes'
```

or if you want to be flash then

```
MERGE
INTO TARGET_TABLE AS t
USING SOURCE_TABLE AS s
    ON t.pk = s.pk
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
    INSERT (pk, a, b) VALUES (pk, a, b)
WHEN MATCHED AND s.a = 'yes' THEN
    UPDATE
    SET b = s.b
;
```

Comment: Thank you both ! I will try and i come back as soon as I can :)